# Error occuring during squashing the commits

Tags: git, notepad++, git-bash

While squashing the commits, I used the command 
`$ git rebase -i master`.

Also I have specified the text editor to be Notepad ++ and used the command
`$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession"`.

I have a 32-bit processor as I am working with my old computer.
When I entered the command it executed but showed a blank window in Notepad++ and when i closed it Git Bash showed the following error:

```
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: line 268: -multiInst: command not found
Could not execute editor
```

Comment: Try removing `-multiInst` from the editor config.